# Getting Value error when attempting to call api with validated user token

Tags: python, django, api

I am trying to get all of my customers recent orders in my app. I sign in as the user, receive a valid token, and try the api. I'm getting this error everytime I attempt to call my api: "ValueError: Cannot query "jake thedogg": Must be "CustomerDetails" instance." I am trying to get all instances of orders from this user.

```
def customer_get_latest_order(request):
    customer = get_user(request)
    if not customer:
        return JsonResponse({'invalid token'})
    order = OrderSerializer(Order.objects.filter(customer=customer).order_by("-id"),
        many=True,
        context={"request": request}
    ).data
    return JsonResponse({"order": order})
```

Model:

```
class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, related_name='order_details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_size = models.ForeignKey(ProductSize, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    sub_total = models.FloatField()

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)
```

Serializers:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerOrderSerializer()
    driver = OrderDriverSerializer()
    dispensary = OrderDispensarySerializer()
    order_details = OrderDetailSerializer(many=True)
    status = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="get_status_display")

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ("id", "customer", "dispensary", 'delivery_signature', 'order_rated', 'quantity',
                  "driver", "order_details", "total", "status", "address", "created_at")
```

Order Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4

    e = 5

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (a, "ah"),
        (b, "bb"),
        (c, "cc"),
        (d, "dd"),

        (CANCELED, "Canceled/Refunded")
    )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delivery_signature = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='delivery_selfie/', blank=True, default='')
    delivered_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    dispensary = models.ForeignKey(Dispensary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(
        Driver, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picked_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    order_rated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    total = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.id)
```

Everytime I try to call the api I get that error.

Comment: You might wanna post the `Order` model as well.

Comment: Added model for clarity

Comment: Issue is the `customer` field of the `Order` model. type of the `customer` field is `CustomerDetails` and you are trying pass a `User` type in your order filter query. based on your current setup, you have to get the `CustomerDetails` first and then pass that to the order filter query. it's better to have a foreign key on the Order model so you can just fetch the orders of that customer.

Comment: I need the data from customer details. How do I get the customer details information in there in relation to the customer model. Every customer has a customer detail but, I can't figure out how to retrieve that.

Comment: You can add a `user/customer` field to the 'Order' model and then retrieve the order from the user. with your current setup, you have to fetch the customer detail object of the user and then pass that to the order query. not sure how you designed the customer details model so can't tell exactly how, but I'm assuming it has a user filed. so you can fetch the details based on the user.